# weight sum for path between two nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

You are given a Tree with n vertices. Every node has an integer weight associated with it.
There are a huge number of queries(~n^2) on the given tree.
for a query (A, B), where A, B are two vertices of the tree, you need to calculate sum of weights of the nodes on the unique path from A to B, including A and B.

I can do dfs/bfs for individual queries but that is going to take O(n^3) for ~n^2 possible queries..
can anyone suggest something better which takes less than O(n) per query?

thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tree is not rooted, make any arbitrary node the root of the tree.

We'll denote weight of the node x with W[x] and sum of weights of all nodes from root to node x with C[x].

Now let's assume there's a query like, `u, v`:

We've to find the Lowest Common Ancestor of node u and v. Let's assume the LCA of u and v is P. so the result for query (u,v) will be `C[u]-C[P]+C[v]-C[P]+W[P]`

Comment: doesn't work for the following case.. n=4, each vertex with weight 1, edges (1,2), (2, 3), (2,4).. lets take node 4 as root, C[1]=2, C[3]=2, C[2]=1, (query(1,3) = 2) != C[1]+C[3]

Comment: @imagin: sorry, I misunderstood the problem. Please check the edited answer and actually for the graph you gave, C[4]=1, C[2]=2, C[3]=3, C[1]=3

Comment: finding LCA for (u, v) will take O(n).. that doesn't decrease the complexity.. suggest something better than O(n) for each query

Comment: @imagin: ouch. . .There are algorithms to find LCA in O(lg(N)) and O(sqrt(N)). Learn LCA first. . .

Comment: @imagin: glad to know it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your problem very similar to [Timus Online Judge 1471.Tree](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1471) ?
The only difference is that nodes are weighted in your problem while edges are weighted in Ural 1471.Tree.

This is a typical LCA problem.

Make anyone of the nodes as the root of the tree(if necessary), then calculate the distance dist[i] of every other nodes to the root, which takes O(N) time using BFS/DFS.
Then for each query(A,B), find the LCA L of (A,B), then the distance between of (A,B) is
dist[A] + dist[B] - 2*dist[L].

However, in your problem, it may be necessary to convert the node weight to edge weight.

If you are not familiar with the LCA algorithm, [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor) is a very good site that may help you.